# Creating a list of dictionary values using only list comprehention

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionary. I want to convert the keys of the dictionary using only list comprehension but I'm unable to do it.

My code snippet is written below:

```
final_answers = [{'abc': True, 'def': True}]

final_answers = [[values for values in dict_.values()] for dict_ in final_answers[0]]
```

But it is given an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
File "<string>", line 3, in <listcomp>
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: try `for dict_ in final_answers[0].items()` else you only iterate on the keys, but then.... well what is your expected output? because your list comprehension is completely wrong

Comment: `final_answers = [list(dict_.values()) for dict_ in final_answers]`. However here you are converting values, not keys

Comment: yes, but OP is talking about keys too... and provides an example with values...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a list containing only the keys from the dictionaries within the first list,is this the result you are expecting `[['abc', 'def']]` ?

Comment: I am expecting [True, True] @MKDYasserH

Answer (score 2):

You are now using `values()` to the key of the dict, while you should use it to the dict itself, so it should be:

```
final_answers = [{'abc': True, 'def': True}]
final_answers = [value for value in final_answers[0].values()]
print(final_answers) # Output: [True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `final_answers[0]` is the dictionary, and the `dict_` are the keys, so this is how you should get the values

```
final_answers = [{'abc': True, 'def': True}]
final_answers = [final_answers[0][str_] for str_ in final_answers[0]]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark the answer as the solution to your question?

Comment: Btw, the @adamkwm's answer is better in computing time and looks nicer, so I would prefer to use that